# Почему некорректно выводится строка в консоли?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ввожу слова в одну строку через консоль. Далее, выводит все кроме первого слова. Как вывести полную строку?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str[100];
    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    (cin >> str).get();
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    cout << str;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: cin читает до пробела.

Comment: Я ввожу 5 слов, но выводит только 4. Первое что я вел- куда-то пропало. Есть альтернативные варианты ввода текста в одну строку и вывода?

Comment: `(cin >> str).get();` это зачем?

Answer (score 3):

Уберите эту странную конструкцию :)

```
(cin >> str).get();
```

Она считывает первое слово в `str`, потом читает пробел.
Потом вы считываете все остальное в `str` *заново*, затирая первое слово.

Comment: Если просто cin>>str;  то такой же эффект

Comment: @AlekseyTkachenko Вам предлагают убрать упомянутую строку целиком. С `cin` использовать только `getline`.